# How to prevent some data from synchronization in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

In my app, user can create notes and add images to it while being offline.

`Images` will be stored in Firebase Storage
`Notes`(text and links to images) in Firebase Realtime Database

I want to sync `note` only when every `image` that dependent on this `note` is uploaded to Firebase Storage. How can I prevent some notes from being synchronized until every image from this notes will be uploaded?

Comment: I typically accomplish this by writing the downloadURL of the image into the database. This URL is only available after the upload of the image has completed, so it nicely covers that condition. See the `OnSuccessListener ` here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file

Answer (score 1):

You can do as Frank says and sync to the Database on complete. See [Zero to App: Develop with Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE), and it's associated [Android sample code](https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c).

If you want do this server side, the best way to do this is probably to spin up a Node.js server and watch for an image to be uploaded ([Object Change Notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) may be useful here).

In the future, [Google Cloud Functions](http://cloud.google.com/functions) will be the best way to watch for changes when a file is uploaded.

Comment: I will watch provided video in few days. As I understand, Firebase Database is synchronizing automatically. Is there any way to prevent it? Then I want to turn on synchronization back when every image is uploaded.(i will check it via `OnSuccessListener`)